# Helix Swarm - Review Creation faulty "revision of 1"

Tags: perforce

I am now using Helix Swarm for quite a while but as up recently an error that some users are affected by started to occur.

When users request the review of a changelist the review is sucessfully created but it displays "[revsion of 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uX6iS.png)" (it should usually say revision x of x, so in that case 1 of 1).

Neither does it display the [amount of changed lines](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BhWhq.png).

The review can mostly be done as normal, but **updating it from Perforce doesnt work** and it **can not be approved by anyone**.

I am at somewhat of a loss, since there is no ressources in the internet where even to begin with debugging.

I have checked out all logs (syslog, helix core log, swarm log) and none of them seem to yield anything interesting. The PHP config seems to be configured correctly (using ssl and all that), worker respawns are set up in cron, all other configs seem to be fine...

And then again, neither does it happen every review, nor does it affect any users in particular.

Any input is appreciated!

**Swarm Version:** SWARM/2023.1/2414875

**Swarm Extension Version:** 2023.1/2414875

**Helix Core Version:** P4D/LINUX26X86_64/2023.1/2442900

**OS:** Ubuntu Server 20.04.6 LTS

Update 08.20.23:

I have figured out, the condition that triggers the broken reviews is when the reviews contain binary files.

Comment: This would indicate messed up Swarm meta-data.  
How did you create the review - P4V's create review OR adding #review to the shelve changelist?
I'd recommend contacting support if you're supported.  
In the past, a messed up review means its unusable forever - create a new one then ignore the problematic one (archive or obliterate if you can and aren't going to contact support..)

Comment: Thanks for your reply! The team is using P4Vs "Create Review" function. Sadly we are not eligible for support. Going forward we will try the #review way. Do you have any advise how to go about validating Swarms Metadata?

Comment: Update: Using the #review keyword, does not mitigate the issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I recently ran into this problem and was able to find a solution. The issue is not binary files being part of the review but rather files marked as exclusive checkout.

The solution was to run

```
p4 configure set filetype.bypasslock=1
```

You will need admin/superuser permissions to do this. I found this answer in their documentation https://www.perforce.com/manuals/swarm/Content/Swarm/setup.post.html#Handling_Exclusive_Locks

Comment: This did indeed resolve the problem .

Answer (score 0):

I also ran into the problem and the issue was from the Swarm workers, the number of tasks was consistently non-0 and large, so I guess basically workers were stuck (3 of them configured at the time).

I solved the problem by reloading the configuration and then starting the workers again.
From the web page with an admin account:

1. Go to the User id drop-down menu
2. Select "*System Information*"
3. Click on the "*Cache Info*" tab
4. Click on the "*Reload Configuration*" button
5. Go to the "*Queue Info*" tab
6. Click on "*Start a worker*"

Comment: In case that issue returns (which it might, if you haven't set it up yet):

You need to set up a Cron Job that respawns the workers every so often.
https://www.perforce.com/manuals/swarm/Content/Swarm/setup.worker.html